# What is the name of the navigation slider(mostly) on the right of a webpage called?

Tags: html, navigation, slider

What is the name of the HTML element shown below? I am trying to research how I can change how it looks like on a page, but I don't know how it is called. I have tried searching slider navigation slider e.t.c... but these are different things. So, what is it called?

[image: navigation slider]

Comment: first of all that is not a html element, and it is called scrollbar.[have a look at this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/) for styling and more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called scroll bar, Below you can see how it can be added

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.ex1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

div.ex2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.ex3 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: auto;
}

div.ex4 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: visible;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The overflow Property</h1>

<p>The overflow property specifies whether to clip content or to add scrollbars when an element's content is too big to fit in a specified area.</p>

<h2>overflow: scroll:</h2>
<div class="ex1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>

<h2>overflow: hidden:</h2>
<div class="ex2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>

<h2>overflow: auto:</h2>
<div class="ex3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>

<h2>overflow: visible (default):</h2>
<div class="ex4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>

</body>
</html>
```